# Solving "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules" with Network Unreachable

Tags: boot, networking, kernel, do-release-upgrade

I used `do-release-upgrade` to move from 14.04 to 16.04.  It seemed to go through, although there were a number of packages listed afterwards that were not upgraded successfully.

Booting straight into 16.04 the system halts with:

```
Failed to start Load Kernel Modules
  See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service' 
[ OK ] Started Journal Service 
.....
[ OK ] Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice
```

I went to try `dpkg --configure -a` from Recovery Mode, following [What to do after Failed to start Load Kernel Modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules)

This failed because I have no network access (`ping` gives `Network is unreachable`)

This is when I have a network cable connection, that works fine when I boot a live image on the same laptop

Comment: Have also used the process outlined on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery.  Can mount the host file system and chroot in fine.  Ping to my router is fine, but apt-get update still fails.

Comment: 'root@ubuntu:/# nameserver 208.67.222.222

...........

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ImportError: No module named 'gdbm''

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean install over my system partitions, keeping my home partition, because there were all kinds of messages about missing perl libraries when trying to configure the network.  Installed my most frequently used apps from the command line, and the config settings in my home partition meant that I am up and running again.