# Failed to start Load Kernel Modules after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, kernel, display, opengl, 18.04

After I upgrade Kubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04, and restarted it, all I'm seeing is my mouse cursor, which responds to my movements, and that's pretty much it. I tried to see if I can start up sddm, but that failed.

After running `journalctl -xe`, this is the entry when it tried to start up systemd-modules-load.service:

```
systemd-modules-load[1858]: Failed to find module 'ashmem_linux'
systemd-modules-load[1858]: Failed to find module 'binder_linux'
systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules
```

I also checked `/etc/modules`, but they're empty.

I tried disabling Secure Boot from Lenovo's BIOS, but it won't let me (the option is disabled).

I tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but that didn't work, and neither did `sudo apt install -f`.

The solution I tried: https://askubuntu.com/a/779574/558318

I tried `mokutil --disable-validation`, but that didn't work at all, either.

`dmesg | grep -i failed` returns this:

```
[  0.261240] pci 0000:03:00:00.0: BAR 6: failed to assign [mem size 0x00080000 pref]
[  1.303500] rtc_cmos: probe of 00:01 failed with error -16
[  1.523312] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution in failed \_SB.PCI0.RP05.PEGP.DD02._BCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[  5.313157] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[  5.313161] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[  6.663134] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
```

**This original problem got solved by purging anbox, but it seems that that wasn't the problem at all.  See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028281/plasma-could-not-correctly-use-opengl-2-after-upgrading-to-18-04)**

Comment: Are you able to get to the GRUB menu, or the login screen? If you're able to get to the login screen, click on your username, then the gear icon, and tell me which environment is selected.

Comment: I'm only able to get to the GRUB menu.  The only thing I'm seeing on my login is my mouse cursor on a black screen. @heynnema

Comment: Are you able to get into Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu?

Comment: yup.  However, I can't connect to my network unless I use a wired connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo apt-get purge anbox-*
```

Comment: that solved the Load Kernel Modules problem, but that wasn't the problem after all :-(

Comment: Agreed. Having the same issue. I have to login manually and initiate startx to execute X server