# Plasma Could Not Correctly Use OpenGL 2 after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, intel-graphics, opengl, 18.04

After I upgrade Kubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04, and restarted it, all I'm seeing is my mouse cursor, which responds to my movements, and that's pretty much it. I tried to see if I can start up sddm, but that failed.

I got to login by installing slick-greeter and use that instead.

After logging in, the message says:

> Plasma is unable to start as it could not correctly use OpenGL 2.  Please check that your graphics drivers are set up correctly.

I checked the environment variable `$DISPLAY`, but it seems to be unset.

I tried reinstalling `plasma-desktop`, `sddm`, `mesa` drivers, `xorg`, `xserver-xorg*intel`, `kde*`, `kwin`, and `nvidia-340` drivers.

My laptop is a Lenovo Z40 with NVIDIA GT820m (currently disabled and using Intel HD Graphics).

**Update: kinda fixed it**

I'm not gonna mark this as a solution because I prefer to use Intel graphics (better battery life), but I uninstalled `nvidia-340`, and installed `nvidia-384`, and ran `prime-select nvidia`.  That fixed it, but I'm hoping I can run this with Intel graphics.  Another reason why I stuck with Intel Graphics for so long is because of the [weird sleep bug where the laptop would wake up but the screen stays blank](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3222442/nvidia-gtx-780-graphics-card-sleep-problem.html), but it seems to be fixed now.

I did post the bug about the problem [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1767228) and hopefully someone can let me know what was missing.