# Steam error: OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display on laptop running on NVIDIA GPU

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, steam, 18.04, opengl

I currently have `nvidia-390` installed on my system (integrated Intel HD graphics [stopped working for some odd reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028281/plasma-could-not-correctly-use-opengl-2-after-upgrading-to-18-04)).  Steam was working with Intel graphics, and with `nvidia-340`, I believe.  The last time I used the laptop's NVIDIA GPU was a year ago.  Main reason why I'm not using `nvidia-340` (which was recommended on the driver manager) was because it wouldn't run after upgrading to 18.04, and had to use `nvidia-390` and install `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390`.

Yesterday, I tried installing `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396`, and remove anything related to `nvidia-390`.  That fixed my problem, including the menu lag on Kubuntu.  However, I can't use my second display after that, which made me unable to use my laptop afterwards.  I assumed it was because there was no `nvidia-396` package, so I removed `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396`, and re-installed `nvidia-390` and `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390`.  Now, I'm back to where I began.

I tried running `glxinfo`, and this returned:

```
name of display: :0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

My laptop is a [Lenovo Z40](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2463639,00.asp), with Core i7-4510U & GeForce 820M.

`lspci | grep -i vga`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

`lspci | grep -i nvidia`

```
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```