# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't boot after installing Windows (GRUB already repaired)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

After installing Windows 7 on my Laptop normally running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I couldn't boot Ubuntu anymore. GRUB didn't show up on boot and Windows directly started.

After using the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool, the GRUB menu shows up again, but if I try to boot Ubuntu normally, the screen stays black with a blinking cursor in the top left corner.

Booting Ubuntu in recovery mode got stuck always at the same point:
loading some drivers, I guess?
[image: loading some drivers, I guess?]
here I discovered that, if I wait long enough (>5 mins), another prompt appears:
press enter to boot the system
[image: press enter to boot the system]
When Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the recovery mode menu does indeed appear.

When I select `network` here, the system gets stuck again showing first this:
failed to start load kernel modules [image: failed to start load kernel modules]
and then this:
failed to start load kernel modules - again [image: failed to start load kernel modules - again] where it stops doing anything.

Interstingly, If I now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, ubuntu boots and I can login to my user account **BUT with neither WiFi nor USB working**.

On a wired network connection it seems to work somehow (but not for everything, Firefox, for example, couldn't load any website) and I was able to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` where it seemed to be able to connect to the servers but didn't change the situation at all.

After reading through [this Guy's post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules) who seems to have had a very similar problem, I got the following output for `sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service`:
many red lines [image: many red lines]
Too many red lines for my taste, unfortunately, I'm too inexperienced to get what it wants to tell me. 
Unfortunately, [the answer that helped the guy who posted the question above](https://askubuntu.com/a/779574) didn't have any healing effect on my system.

This is where I am right now. The simplest thing to do probably would be to reinstall Ubuntu, but I really would like to avoid all the setting-up-new-system stuff. Any Ideas how I can get my Ubuntu installation to boot normally again (with WiFi and USB working)?

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78451/discussion-on-question-by-linub-ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-boot-after-installing-windo).

Comment: thanks @Seth & sorry, I couldn't move the discussion to a chat because of my lack of reputation

Comment: @linub The reputation requirement has been waived for this discussion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system hanging is due to problems with your Linux kernel files.  It can't find and load the needed drives and is hanging up while trying to find them.

**This can be resolved by running these steps:**

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

Make the variable **X** the drive that you want to use for booting.  Under normal circumstances this drive is `/dev/sda`.

Other important commands to resolve the other errors is to ensure the integrity of your Ubuntu installation with these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

**Note:**
Reinstalling the Linux image fixed the modules errors you were getting.  That also should have fixed your problems with your network drivers and connecting to the Internet.