# Problems with login in Ubuntu 18.04 - Failed to start Load Kernel Modules

Tags: kernel, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I upgraded my Ubuntu release from 16.04 to 18.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade` and following the instructions; the system boots correctly to the login page, but when I click on my user name, it says automatically (I do not enter any password) "Autentication error". Then the screen goes black in just a second and a message "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules" appears, along with many other lines:

[image: Modules Load Error]

So I restarted in recovery mode, used the root shell to run `sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service`, and that's the result:

[image: Modules Load Status]

As suggested in many other topics (for example: [What to do after Failed to start Load Kernel Modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules)), I tried to enter

`apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install`

but I get the message `Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'` (i.e., there is no internet connection), while for

`dpkg --configure -a`

I get `dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system`.

Running `ifconfig` I see this result:

[image: Ifconfig Output]

so I cannot connect to any network.

I could appreciate any help in resolving this (I'm not an expert in Ubuntu)

---

EDIT:

Result from `ifconfig -a`:

[image: ifconfig -a result]

Comment: what kind of connection? wifi or eth? have you seen this? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1124454

Comment: also, if possible, it's better to copy/paste text from command output into your question instead of posting an image of it. thanks!

Comment: also, for ifconfig, did you do: `ifconfig -a` to show all interfaces?

Comment: I tried both wifi and eth. I looked at the link you posted but didn't help. I posted above the result from `ifconfig -a`. 
I'm currently unable to connect to network or using any kind of GUI, so I'm writing from another computer, my only possibility is to take pictures. I'm sorry ( I know copying and pasting would be much better)

Comment: do you have a wired or wireless connection?

Comment: I can connect directly to my router via ethernet cable or use the wifi

Comment: ok, use the direct ethernet connection... I posted an answer, let me know if that works out for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to do in recovery mode is remount the main drive read/write:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then you can try to reconfigure your packages:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

You might need to add a DNS server to connect to the internet:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and add the following to the end:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Save and close.

NOTE - Op had issues writing directly to /etc/resolv.conf:

> The only difficulty I encountered was to save the resolv.conf file in
>   /root directory first and then move it manually to /etc/resolv.conf
>   manually using
>
> ```
> sudo nano resolv.conf
> sudo mv resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
> ```

Then restart networking:

```
sudo service networking restart
sudo ifconfig enp2s0f0 up
sudo dhclient enp2s0f0
```

Then try to run your updates:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt -f install
```

If all goes well reboot.

Comment: It finally worked! Thank you a lot!
The only difficulty I encountered was to save the `resolv.conf` file in `/root` directory first and then move it manually to `/etc/resolv.conf` manually using `sudo mv resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I followed your procedure but something failed, I noticed that now, trying again `resolv.conf` isn't modified as the above steps required. It seems upon reboot I am loosing this...

Comment: resolve.conf will be rewritten at reboot.... this is OK as once you get your system fixed in recovery mode, you will likely need to reconfigure via network settings gui once you get booted into normal mode