# How to fix broken kernel that was partially removed

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

So I'm a super noob with Ubuntu and I was running out of disk space in  Ubuntu 18.04. In order to clean the system, I tried to remove old system kernels with:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-VERSION
```

but ended up mistakenly and foolishly choosing my current system kernel version. After the terminal ran a few processes it then said something along the lines of "continuing might break the system and you will have trouble rebooting, do you want to continue?" of course I said no don't continue and all seemed well after that, until that afternoon, when I tried to turn my laptop back on the errors came up:

[image: Kernel Load Error]

From there pushing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> allowed me to get a command prompt that gave me access to my entire intact file system, I then typed:

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
```

which gave me:

[image: systemctl status]

Then after troubleshooting, I was able to establish a network connection in the recovery root shell which allowed me to successfully run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt -f install
```

as per this similar post: [Problems with login in Ubuntu 18.04 - Failed to start Load Kernel Modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073410/problems-with-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules?newreg=44af5069da024264a9150eb06acf4115)

However, this did not solve the problem, I am still getting the same issues. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Grub, the second option is "Advanced". It will have older kernels you can boot from. If one of them works, Use it to do a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Note that you can remove old kernels (and other packages that are no longer needed) with: `sudo apt autoremove --purge` (safer and easier than trying to uninstall individual packages).

Comment: Thanks for the response Katu, the answer below solved the issue! and thanks Jesper for the tip, will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can boot and run terminal, just issue:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic
```

I recommend running this while having booted a previous (working) kernel version.