# Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables - Cannot connect to ethernet with sudo dhclient enp2s0

Tags: boot, networking, 18.04, kernel, systemd

My system dual boots Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Installed both last year on a new Dell laptop. No problems since then. Wasn't trying to upgrade the distribution as in other similar questions.

I booted Ubuntu 18.04 this week and received "Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables". Then was dropped to the command prompt and logged in as root. Ran

```
system-ctl status systemd-sysctl.service
```

(Three failure results listed at the end of this post - I don't know how to attach the full file.
First two suggest a network problem. Last one suggests a file system error)

Started following the instructions from a post [where this seemed to have been answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073410/problems-with-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules)

All went fine until I tried to start my ethernet (wired connnection)

```
sudo dhclient enp2s0
cmp: EOF on /tmp/tmp.gxb88KcVpV which is empty
```

I can't go any further. Please guide me here - I only have a basic knowledge of Ubuntu. Thanks!

**EDIT:** The log file extracts below were produced while I was on a wireless connection. The error on "dhclient" came up when I was on wired connection

**1.**

```
Aug 19 09:39:39 Inspiron-7472 systemd-udevd[434]: Process '/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --prefix=/net/ipv4/conf/enp2s0 --prefix=/net/ipv4/neigh/enp2s0 --prefix=/net/ipv6/conf/enp2s0 --prefix=/net/ipv6/neigh/enp2s0' failed with exit code 1.
```

Aug 19 09:39:39 Inspiron-7472 kernel: cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
Aug 19 09:39:39 Inspiron-7472 kernel: cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'

**2.**
Aug 19 09:39:40 Inspiron-7472 systemd-udevd[438]: Process '/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --prefix=/net/ipv4/conf/wlp3s0 --prefix=/net/ipv4/neigh/wlp3s0 --prefix=/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0 --prefix=/net/ipv6/neigh/wlp3s0' failed with exit code 1

**3.**
Unit media-windata.mount has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Aug 19 09:39:44 Inspiron-7472 systemd-fsck[933]: /dev/sda3: Inode 6292001 seems to contain garbage.
Aug 19 09:39:44 Inspiron-7472 systemd-fsck[933]: /dev/sda3: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
Aug 19 09:39:44 Inspiron-7472 systemd-fsck[933]:         (i.e., without -a or -p options)
Aug 19 09:39:45 Inspiron-7472 systemd-fsck[933]: fsck failed with exit status 4.
Aug 19 09:39:45 Inspiron-7472 systemd-fsck[933]: Running request emergency.target/start/replace
Aug 19 09:39:45 Inspiron-7472 systemd[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073410/problems-with-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules): systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-432d3483\x2d14c5\x2d461d\x2db21c\x2d965d0bedfeef.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 19 09:39:45 Inspiron-7472 systemd[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073410/problems-with-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules): systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-432d3483\x2d14c5\x2d461d\x2db21c\x2d965d0bedfeef.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 19 09:39:45 Inspiron-7472 systemd[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073410/problems-with-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules): Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/432d3483-14c5-461d-b21c-965d0bedfeef.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-432d3483\x2d14c5\x2d461d\x2db21c\x2d965d0bedfeef.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-432d3483\x2d14c5\x2d461d\x2db21c\x2d965d0bedfeef.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Aug 19 09:39:45 Inspiron-7472 systemd[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073410/problems-with-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules): Dependency failed for /home.
-- Subject: Unit home.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit home.mount has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Aug 19 09:39:45 Inspiron-7472 systemd[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073410/problems-with-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules): Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
-- Subject: Unit local-fs.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

Answer (score 2):

Checked the output again and booted a Live USB.

Ran:

> sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3

Answered "yes" to "Fix all errors" (prompt pops up after manually entering y a few times)

Ran fsck again. Returned no errors. Rebooted and logged in with no errors!