# Cannot login after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, login

I recently tried to upgrade my laptop from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. The upgradation process was smooth; but when I try to log in, it is showing an Authentication Error

[image: Authentication Error]

and then I get this black screen which stays indefinitely

[image: boot messages]

I am a rookie in these regards, so a step-by-step guide will be much helpful. Thanks in advance.

Results after trying [suggestions by Manu Mathur](https://askubuntu.com/a/1125986/527764):

`sudo apt-get update` gives this:

[image: no internet]

`sudo apt-get upgrade` gives this:

[image: nothing to do]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication error at login after online upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131817/authentication-error-at-login-after-online-upgrade-to-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. Logged to TTY and did a shutdown, which lead to other problem. Could log in to TTY anyway (CTRL+ALT+F1). Then I ran:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Helped in my case.
Solution is based on a related [earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules). Configuring did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of these two solutions can help you:

**Solution - I**

- Try logging in the `TTY` mode.
- If you can log in, this means your password is correct. Post login, use the command: 
  `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
- If you do not like `GNOME` on Ubuntu you can go back to the `Unity`.

**How to Login into TTY mode?**

- To access TTY, use this combination:

To access them, use either of these keys combination: use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> keys(or you can also try use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> on 17.10 and newer versions)

**Note:** You can change the keys from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd> to access the terminal that you want)

- If you wish to get back to your GUI session (the normal desktop), try these key combinations:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> keys (or <kbd>F2</kbd> on 17.10 and newer)

**Solution - II**

My second guess is that you might have some broken packages. To check, do the following:

- Switch to a `TTY` mode, example: use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> keys, and login to the command line
- Once you are in the command line, run the command: `sudo apt install -f` and see if that helps

**P.S.** If you own a "Dell" laptop, then see if you have **AMDGPU-pro** driver installed. It is also known to conflict with the upgrade process. If you find it, just remove it using the "TTY" command.

Keep us posted via the comments section.

Comment: Please instruct how to login in `TTY` mode.

Comment: I have included the process between the two solutions @SubhajitPaul.

Comment: I am editing my question with the snapshots to show you the results of your suggestions.

Comment: That would be great. Thank you.