# Ubuntu 19.04 won't boot. Upgrade from ISO?

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.04, 19.10

I recently upgraded my monitor to a 34" ultrawide. Everything seemed fine, but the integrated graphics seemed a bit laggy. So, I installed the Nvidia graphics drivers `sudo apt install nvidia-3XX` and rebooted. (Following this [guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux))

**Problems!!** My computer now won't boot. I tried switching the monitor back out to no avail.

Current OS: Ubuntu 19.04

### What I've tried so far

I've followed the suggestions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120198/how-to-fix-boot-into-initramfs-prompt-and-mount-cant-read-etc-fstab-no-su) and [here](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/) and can boot into Grub 2.0. My boot appears to be on `sda6`

```
grub> set root=(hd0,msdos6)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-<file> root=/dev/sda6
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.<file>
grub> boot
```

If I boot normally, I get a broken boot. And if I boot in recovery mode, I see a similar problem as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules) but I'm unable to enter command line via `CTRL+ALT+F1` as the OP suggests.

Both regular boot and boot from grub show me something like these images: https://photos.app.goo.gl/HLvNJX7eLkdN5EBy9

One thing I'm considering is upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10. I've burned the ISO onto a USB stick, but install isn't offering an upgrade option; just a split partition ("Install Ubuntu 19.10 alongside Ubuntu 19.04"). I don't want to lose my files on 19.04; but I'm perfectly happy upgrading to 19.10. I don't need or want both OS.

**Question:** How do I upgrade from ISO image? Or how do I recover files from a non-bootable 19.04 so that I can just erase and reinstall? I've also got a Windows VM attached to 19.04 which I don't want to lose files from. Any help appreciated!!

**Edit:** I decided to just erase the 19.04 install and associated files and re-install with 19.10

Comment: What's `nvidia-320`? There is no such thing in the repositories.

Comment: @mikewhatever I've probably just got the wrong number (I didn't write it down)

Comment: Did you verify download of ISO https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and write to install media https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  ?  Second step particularly is where I'd start.  To install from ISO use something else, existing partitions but NO format; it notes your installed packages, erase system directories, installs, re-adds back additional packages you installed (if available) without touching user data providing you don't have format selected - so always backup.

Comment: re:  the last comment re-install: because it erases system directories, global settings stored in system directories will be erased so any config/changes made on those directories are lost so have those backed up. It does keep certain files in those directories but they are system files and not user configs that may have been added