# How to access existing files when you have booted from USB due to load kernel module error

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery, usb-installation, reinstall

A couple of years ago I received a desktop computer through a local program that had Edubuntu installed (I am afraid I do not know the release number).  Recently the software updater advised that an updated release was available and I attempted to install it however during the update my computer froze and a family member shut it down.  When I restarted it, it failed to boot, citing a "failed to start load kernel modules" error.  I have tried several remedies suggested on this site to fix the problem, in particular what has been suggested on this thread [https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules)  These suggestions did not resolve the issue for me.

I did not have many programs installed that I care to recover, I did however have various .odt, .doc and .pdf files I would like to recover, and if possible I would also like to reinstall Ubuntu so I can continue to use the machine.

I have managed to boot using a USB stick with Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS.  Now that I have booted, how can I go about accessing my files?

I see here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation that I should have the option to "Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS" while installing but that option is not listed for me.

Instead I have the option to "Install Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS alongside Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS".  If I choose this option will I still be able to access my old files while operating in Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose "Install Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS alongside Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"

AND you did not take the deliberate and detailed steps required to [encrypt your /home directory](https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/),

you will be able to access the old files while operating in Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS.

Most folks don't encrypt, and you'd know it if you did.